# Is this a bug in STL? Why do we need operator overloading in this Structure?

Tags: c++, stl, operator-overloading

I came across this code for Equal_range, and being very new to C++, it is not clear to me why we need to overload the operator **even though we have created a new compare function**.

**Moreover, could we have used:**

```
bool compare( const S& s, const S& s2 )
{
    return s.number < s2.number;
}
```

instead.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
    int number;
    char name;

    S ( int number, char name  )
        : number ( number ), name ( name )
    {}

    // only the number is relevant with this comparison
    bool operator< ( const S& s ) const
    {
        return number < s.number;
    }
};

struct Comp
{
    bool operator() ( const S& s, int i )
    {
        return s.number < i;
    }

    bool operator() ( int i, const S& s )
    {
        return i < s.number;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // note: not ordered, only partitioned w.r.t. S defined below
    std::vector<S> vec = { {1,'A'}, {2,'B'}, {2,'C'}, {2,'D'}, {4,'G'}, {3,'F'} };

    auto p = std::equal_range(vec.begin(),vec.end(),2,Comp());

    for ( auto i = p.first; i != p.second; ++i )
        std::cout << i->name << ' ';
}
```

EDIT: The link to the code is http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example code, your various methods of comparing all do different things; the `operator<` overload allows you to compare an `S` with another `S`, where as the `Comp` struct allows you to compare an `S` with an `int` and vise-versa.

If you read the documentation for [`equal_range`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/equal_range/)

> The elements are compared using operator< for the first version, and
>   comp for the second

You see that you need to be able to do both `a[n] < a[i]` and `comp(a[n], val)`, the first to compare items in the list to other items in the list, and the second to be able to compare items in the list to the `val` parameter of the `equal_range` call. Hence why you need both an operator overload and a comparison method.

Comment: Why doesn't it call the comp struct for both comparisons?  Why does it still rely on operator< ?

Comment: This answer is wrong. The documentation says that the overload that does not take a comparator uses `operator<`, but in the code above the only call to `equal_range` explicitly passes the comparator and the operator should not be used (if it is, raise a bug against the implementation).

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a bug in your STL implementation.  The [C++ standard](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/equal_range/) explicitly states it will not call operator< in this case:

> The elements are compared using operator< for the first version, and
>   **comp for the second**. Two elements, a and b are considered equivalent
>   if (!(a<b) && !(b<a)) or if (!comp(a,b) && !comp(b,a)).

"First version" refers to the version where no comparison class is provided.  "second" refers to the version you used.

I tried this out on VS2013 but it doesn't even compile.  The error is:

> error C2664: 'bool Comp::operator ()(const S &,int)' : cannot convert
>   argument 1 from 'S' to 'int'

Unfortunately, the error is deep down inside Microsoft's obfuscated STL implementation.  Why would it call operator()(const S&, int) instead of operator()(int, const S&) ?

So I think Visual Studio's STL implementation is wrong.  And if your compiler requires it, I think its STL is also wrong.  I wonder if they just never tested this where the third argument is not the same type as what is returned by the iterator.

I would love to hear other people's thoughts on this.